Rank of a matrix with trace and determinant zero.
We have a $3×3$ matrix $A$ such that $\text{Tr}(A)=0$ and $ \text{det}(A)=0$ then what are the possible values of $\text{rank}(A)$?
My working: Let $x,y,z$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ then $x+y+z=0$ since $\text{Tr}(A)=0$ and $xyz=0$ since $ \text{det}(A)=0$. The rank of a matrix is equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues of the matrix, thus the possible values of $\text{rank}(A)$ are $0$ and $2$. It cannot be $3$, since atleast one of the eigenvalues need to be zero, it cannot be $1$, since if two eigenvalues are zero, the conditions of the equation force the last to be zero as well.
Though this analysis seems correct to me, the place where I found this question lists the correct answer to be $0,1,2$ as the possible values of $\text{rank}(A)$ of which I cannot make sense. Is my working correct, or am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

Your claim "The rank of a matrix is equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues of the matrix" is correct if the matrix is diagonalizable, but in general is not right, as we see now.
Since $\det A=0$, it holds $\mathrm{rk}(A)<3$, and it is easy to provide examples with  $\mathrm{rk}(A)=0,1,2$:
$$\mathrm{rk}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}=0,\quad 
\mathrm{rk}\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}=1,\quad 
\mathrm{rk}\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}=2.$$

You probably meant to say "is correct if the matrix is diagonalizable"

@jjagmath, Yes sure! Thanks!

Beautiful answer.
